# Why is there increase in heap size when using string stream despite full deallocation?

Tags: visual-studio, heap-memory, c++20, stringstream

Using the VS (Community 2022 & Windows 10) diagnostic tool->Memory Usage (Heap), we see an increase in heap size of 0.46kb when reading input at: "stream >> temp;". This increase persists to the end of the program as per +0.46kb reported at "return 0;".
No memory leaks are reported by either of the _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() calls.

What is the reason for this increase in heap usage? (The heap size has been a great way to verify memory management up-to now, usage of std::cout has a similar effect as an increase in allocation that lasts until program end)

(The allocations and deallocations are included to avoid compiler optimizations)

The following code compiles on Visual studio community edition 2022 in both C++14 and C++20.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <assert.h>
#endif

#include <sstream>

void debug() {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "5.2 22.1 4.2 5.5\n";
    double* ptr{ nullptr };

    while (stream) {
        double temp{ 0 };
        stream >> temp;
        if (stream) {
            ptr = new double;
            delete ptr;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    {
        debug();
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may not be a leak, everything is deallocated once the program ends.

Comment: The CRT in general has no reason to immediately reduce the memory usage of a heap when an object is released.  It simply adds the allocation back to the free list, to be used by a future allocation of equal or lesser size.  Favor a memory profiler suitable for your platform and toolset to get accurate memory usage info, nothing much wrong with _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() or the Diagnostic Tools included with later VS versions.